# How do I display the indeterminate spinner ProgressBar in Vaadin Flow?

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14, vaadin23

Below is the code to display an indeterminate `ProgressBar` in Vaadin Flow (version 23):

```
ProgressBar spinner = new ProgressBar();
spinner.setIndeterminate(true);
spinner.setVisible(true);
```

The only thing is that this now seems to create a `ProgressBar` that goes back and forth and I'm wondering if it's possible to have it display as a circle. I could do it by loading an Icon, an animated GIF and so on, but is it possible through the `ProgressBar` class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bending some component to your will might just be a waste of time.  Flow
allows extremely easy integration of HTML/CSS/JS, so just create your
own spinner (there are many examples out there).

E.g.

Spinner:

```
@CssImport('./spinner.css')
@Tag('spinner')
class Spinner extends Div {}
```

And the `spinner.css`:

```css
spinner {
    width: 4em;
    height: 4em;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    border: 5px solid blue;
    border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
    border-radius: 50%;
    animation: spinner-animation 1s cubic-bezier(0.5, 0, 0.5, 1) infinite;
}

@keyframes spinner-animation {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```